# Merging Immutable.js Maps in Flux store with internal React component state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux, immutable.js

I have been slowly converting my React+Flux apps to use Immutable.js data structures. I use the original, vanilla FB implementation of Flux.

One problem I have encountered is **mixing component state with state received from Flux stores**.

I keep all important business-logic state in stores. But my rule has been to keep UI-related state within components. Stores don't need to concern themselves if, for example, a dropdown menu is open or not, right?

The problem comes when an action is taken in a component that changes state in that same component's store. Let's say we have a component with a dropdown menu that is open. An item is selected from that dropdown menu. The action propagates to the `ItemStore`, the store emits a change, and the component gets new state from the store.

```
_onChange() {
  this.setState(this._getState());
}
_getState() {
  if(this.state === undefined) {
    return {
      data: Immutable.Map({
        selectedItem: ItemStore.getSelectedItem(),
        items: ItemStore.getItems(),
        menuIsOpen: false
      })
    };
  }
  return {
    data: this.state.data.merge(Immutable.Map({
      selectedItem: ItemStore.getSelectedItem(),
      items: ItemStore.getItems(),
      menuIsOpen: this.state.data.get("menuIsOpen")
    }))
  };
}
```

Concurrently, in the component, the click on the dropdown menu item emits an old-fashioned `onClick` event. I have a `_handleClick` function which uses setState to close the dropdown menu (local state).

```
_handleClick(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  this.setState({
    data: this.state.data.set("menuIsOpen", !this.state.data.get("menuIsOpen"))
  });
}
```

The problem is that `_handleClick` ends up being called so soon after  `_getState` that it doesn't have an updated copy of `this.state.data`. So in the component's `render` method, `this.state.data.get("selectedItem")` still shows the previously-selected item.

When I do this with POJOs, React's `setState` seems to batch everything correctly, so it was never an issue. But I don't want to have state that is not part of an Immutable.Map, because I want to take advantage of "pure" `render`ing. Yet I don't want to introduce UI state into my stores, because I feel like that could get messy real quick.

Is there a way I could fix this? **Or is it just a bad practice to merge local Immutable.Map state and Immutable.Map store state within a single component?**

RELATED: I am not a fan of the boilerplate `if(this.state === undefined)` logic to set initial local `menuIsOpen` state in my `_getState` method. *This may be a sign that I am trying to do something that is not correct.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a callback to [`setState`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate) to enqueue an atomic update.

```js
_onChange() {
  this.setState(state => this._getState(state));
}
_getState(state) {
  if(state === undefined) {
    return {
      data: Immutable.Map({
        selectedItem: ItemStore.getSelectedItem(),
        items: ItemStore.getItems(),
        menuIsOpen: false
      })
    };
  }
  return {
    data: state.data.merge(Immutable.Map({
      selectedItem: ItemStore.getSelectedItem(),
      items: ItemStore.getItems(),
      menuIsOpen: state.data.get("menuIsOpen")
    }))
  };
}
```

About your related point, you might want to take a look at [`getInitialState`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#getinitialstate).

Comment: Passing a function to `setState` is the definitive solution; I totally did not know about that. Also, re: `getInitialState`: since my components are using ES6 classes, that method does not exist. And since my component class inherits from a `ImmutableFluxComponent` class, I was setting initial state in the parent's `constructor`. But now that I am using a `_getState` with a `state` param, I can just pass in an empty Immutable.Map to initialize state.data without the `if` statement. So 2 problems solved. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Why have 2 separate actions occur when you click (fire action to store, close menu)?  Instead, you could say, when they click a menu item, we need to close the menu item, and alert the store of the new value.

```
_handleClick(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  this.setState({
    data: this.state.data.set("menuIsOpen", false)
  }, function() {
    alertTheSelectionChange(selectedItem)
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this would've worked as well—I did not know about the 2nd callback param to `setState`, either. But passing a function to `setState` is a little cleaner in my case.